# Error deploying rails app on elastic beanstalk (production mode)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I'm experiencing an error that's preventing my app on Amazon EB (elastic beanstalk from starting) ... after looking at the logs, this is the only section that looks like there a bug ... note the section that mentions mysql.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/production.log
-------------------------------------
  passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'


I, [2013-11-25T15:15:27.080960 #10181]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 212.49.88.109 at 2013-11-25 15:15:27 +0000
F, [2013-11-25T15:15:27.093868 #10181] FATAL -- : 
Mysql2::Error (Host 'ip-10-72-151-230.eu-west-1.compute.internal' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'):
  mysql2 (0.3.13) lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `connect'
  mysql2 (0.3.13) lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2745626355944311791__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Any idea what could be wrong? The app works fine on locally (the app connects to RDS on production).

Ps: Feel free to ask questions in the comments so that I can refine my question and explain context. Just don't know what information is needed at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have a security group assigned to your elastic beanstalk environment that provides access to your RDS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html